# How to get pivot data depends model binding

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I am using in Pivot model. In previously i assigned `user_id` is routekey but now i want to match model binding flats (`flat_id`) also. I have attached the output screenshot too.

My url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/apartments/1/flats/2/flat-members/3

```
    namespace App\pivotes;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
    use App\models\RoleUser;
    use App\models\Flat;
    use App\models\Association;
    use App\models\Role;
    use App\User;

    class FlatUser extends Pivot
    {
        protected $table = 'flat_user';

        public $timestamps = false;

        public function getRouteKeyName()
        {
            return 'user_id';
        }

        public function flat()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Flat::class, 'flat_id', 'id');
        }

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
        }

        public function role()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id', 'id');
        }
    }
```

**Update** I tired this

In `RouteServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Route::bind('flat_member', function ($value) {
            dd(\App\pivotes\FlatUser::where('flat_id', request()->route()->parameter('flat'))->where('user_id', request()->route()->parameter('flat_member'))->first());

            return \App\pivotes\FlatUser::where('flat_id', request()->route()->parameter('flat'))->where('user_id', request()->route()->parameter('flat_member'))->first() ?? abort(404);
        });


    }
```

for `dd()` I am getting correct data, but if I am returning it, it seems to be becoming empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am using RouteServiceProvider.php. I check flat_id and route parameter flats whether it matches, giving particular pivot model data. In below added my codes. 

public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        Route::bind('flat_member', function ($value) {
            return \App\pivotes\FlatUser::where('flat_id', request()->route()->parameter('flat'))->where('user_id', request()->route()->parameter('flat_member'))->first() ?? abort(404);
        });
    }
```